# receiving the following error using solana cli "Error: RPC response error -32003: Transaction signature verification failure"

Tags: solana-cli, error

I am using the following commands to try and send Solana and am receiving "Error: RPC response error -32003: Transaction signature verification failure"

```
solana transfer --from <file path> <recipient public address> <amount> --allow-unfunded-recipient --url https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com --fee-payer <file path>
```

and

```
solana transfer <recipient public address> <amount> --allow-unfunded-recipient
```

I have tried the Mainnet-beta cluster and a private RPC node.  Both are returning the same error

Answer (score 1):

The error `Transaction signature verification failure` usually happens when you are signing with the incorrect key, or the transaction is missing a required signature.

Verify that the `--from` and `--fee-payer` are correct. If you are transferring from an account, the `--from` should sign this transaction.